# How to make a lowercase trademark / TM sign in HTML5?

Tags: html, special-characters

I know that `&trade;` creates an upper case TM sign like so: ™.

I was wondering if it was possible to do the same thing with a lowercase "tm"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<sup>`:

```
<sup>tm</sup>
```

For example:

```
Testing<sup>tm</sup>
```

Generates (since it is one of the allowed HTML tags in SO's markdown):

Testing<sup>tm</sup>